# Как согласовать название книги?

Tags: согласование, литература

Название одной из книг — "История Вселенной".
Книга "История Вселенной". "История Вселенной" — приложение к слову "книга".

Как согласовать: во второй из книг, "История Вселенной", рассматривались вопросы...

или:

во второй из книг, "Истории Вселенной", рассматривались вопросы...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В "Истори**и** Вселенной", второй книге этой серии (второй из этих книг),
>   рассматривались...
>
> Во второй книге, "Истори**я** Вселенной", рассматривались вопросы...